# Как правильно провести рефакторинг "Божественного Объекта"?

Tags: ооп, c++, рефакторинг

Вот здесь переменная 
std::string текст;
Требуется в 3 классах потомках.
вместе с методом 
void set_text();

```
struct GUI
{
POSITION position;// общий для всех

//std::string текст; вынести сюда?
//void set_text(const std::string & текст_){текст=текст_;}
};

struct TEXT : public GUI
{
std::string текст;
void set_text(const std::string & текст_){текст=текст_;}
}

struct BUTTON : public GUI
{
std::string текст;
void set_text(const std::string & текст_){текст=текст_;}
}

struct IMAGE : public GUI
{

}

struct INPUT : public GUI
{
std::string текст;
void set_text(const std::string & текст_){текст=текст_;}
}
```

Мне проще её вынести в struct GUI чтобы была одна точка доступа.
Но тогда IMAGE будет хранить лишний string.

Пока вижу несколько вариантов:

1. Если в подклассах переменных
       требуется больше чем не требуется то
       выносить в родительский класс.
2. Создать дополнительный родительский
       класс и от него наследоваться тем
       классам, которым требуется string
       текст. Если есть несколько общих переменных для ряда классов- применять множественное наследование.
3. Хранить в родительском
       классе только то, что общее для всех
       иначе прописывать для каждого
       элемента.

В настоящем коде всего 15 элементов и текст требуется в 9.
Всего переменных и структур в GUI 115(ровно) и памяти на 100 разных экземпляров GUI жрёт под 400 mb.
Поэтому надо сейчас всё обдумать и грамотно спроектировать.

---

---

Обновление:

Ух.. Попробую показать основной хребет.
Каждый GUI
имеет 2 обязательных метода
update()
draw()

то есть одна update() функция обновляет состояние всех переменных.
другая draw() передаёт данные на отрисовку.
Draw не может и не имеет права ничего изменять в GUI, она просто вызывает методы низкоуровневых библиотек по отрисовке.

update() как раз проверяет есть ли мышь над ним, передвигает ползунок, перелистывает страницу и.т.д. то есть изменяет члены данных.

Сейчас вот так:

```
struct GUI
{
TYPE_GUI type;
POSITION position;

IMAGE_LIB * image_фон;

... еще 100 переменных

update(){

if(type==IMAGE){if(key_left == true){key_left =false; position.X += 10; image_фон->X = position.X;}}
if(type==TEXT){..}
...
}

draw()
{

if(type==IMAGE){image_фон->render();}
if(type==TEXT){..}
...
}
}

std::map<string , GUI*> gui_elements;

void game_thread()
{
gui_elements["map1"]->set_pos_X(unit_X);
}

void gui_thread()
{
for{
gui_elements->update();
}
}

void render_thread()
{
for{
gui_elements->draw();
}
}
```

> game-thread - может записывать в
> экземпляр gui-elements. остальные
> потоки только читают, когда есть
> обновления состояния выполненных в
> потоке game-thread.

Comment: Логичнее вариант 2.

Comment: Мне такой подход кажется интересным, но вот в wiki написано:

"Существует мнение, что множественное наследование — это неверная концепция, порождённая неверным анализом и проектированием."

Может есть другие варианты?

Comment: А также есть мнение, что наследования вообще стоит избегать, отдавая, где это возможно, предпочтение композиции.

Comment: то есть как?
Как то так что ли?


    struct GUI
    {
    POSITION position;
    
    TEXT   * text;
    BUTTON * button;
    IMAGE  * image;
    
    или вообще один
    void   * el; ??
    
    GUI(type)
    {
    text=0;
    button=0;
    image=0;
    el=0;  
    if(type==TEXT){text=new TEXT;       -или- el=new TEXT;} 
    if(type==BUTTON){button=new BUTTON; -или- el=new BUTTON;} 
    if(type==IMAGE){image=new IMAGE;    -или- el=new IMAGE;} 
    }
    
    };

Comment: Главное воткнуть в GUI таблицу состояний чтобы каждый раз не писать многомерные условия типа:

 if (button.visible) && (button.enabled) && (button.focused) && (button1.x<cursor.x) {button1.click()}. 

Вместо этого хорошо работает ассоциативный массив указателей на функцию с ключом равным хэшем от текущего состояния элемента.

Comment: @manking, формально рассматривая **только** приведенные Вами поля классов, возникает вопрос, а зачем вообще нужен GUI?

Я понимаю, что в самом деле структура данных сложнее. Без понимания основных операция Вашего приложения, трудно дать конкретный совет.

Comment: в вопросе обновил данные.

Comment: update и draw очень хотят стать виртуальными методами.

Comment: Собственно, насчёт множественного наследования: его как раз и нужно избегать, переходя от наследования к композиции.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы попробовал заменить наследование композицией:

```
// обратите внимание, тут нет никакого наследования
class ImageHelper
{
    IMAGE_LIB * image_фон;

public:
    void update(Coordinates coord) { ... }
    void draw(Coordinates coord) { ... }
};

class TextHelper
{
    std::string text;

public:
    void update(Coordinates coord) { ... }
    void draw(Coordinates coord) { ... }
    void setText(std::string newText) { text = std::move(newText); ... }
};

class GuiObect
{
    // TYPE_GUI больше не нужен
public:
    virtual void update();
    virtual void draw();
};

class TextControl : public GuiObject
{
    // has one text
    TextHelper text;

public:
    virtual void update()
    {
        // prepare coordinates
        text.update(coordinates);
    }

    virtual void draw()
    {
        // prepare coordinates
        text.draw(coordinates);
        // maybe draw borders etc.
    }
};

class Button : public GuiObject
{
    // has one text and maybe one bg image
    TextHelper text;
    ImageHelper* background;

public:
    virtual void update()
    {
        // prepare coordinates
        if (background) background->update(coordinates);
        text.update(coordinates);
    }

    virtual void draw()
    {
        // prepare coordinates
        if (background) background->draw(coordinates);
        text.draw(coordinates);
        // maybe draw borders etc.
    }
};
// etc.
```

Таким образом, вся логика работы с текстовой строкой уходит в TextHelper, а ваши контролы просто содержат в себе один или несколько экземпляров TextHelper, если нужно, и проксируют вызовы setText и т.д. к нужному объекту TextHelper.

Не уверен, что это лучший вариант, но может быть, это то, что нужно.

Comment: Я кажется понял суть. Это видимо какой то шаблон проектирования называемый helper?
Я его не встречал. И не могу найти конкретной информации по нему.

Правильно ли я понимаю, что преимущество подобного подхода в экономии памяти и производительности?
То есть при наследовании идет вынужденная инициализация даже в том случаи если данные не нужны?

Если бы класс
class Button : public GuiObject

наследовал еще и ImageHelper*
то всегда происходило бы конструирование ImageHelper вместе со всеми его данными?
Или есть еще что то что не вижу?

Comment: @manking: Хм, я не знаю, есть ли такой шаблон проектирования. Я бы просто назвал это [composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern). Главное преимущество, на мой вкус, состоит в разделении полномочий: все операции с текстом отходят отдельной сущности, которая по существу не является контролом.

Comment: @VladD, похоже так. 

Только по минимуму координаты в GuiObject видимо надо добавить (а то непонятно, откуда они берутся в вызовах text.Draw()), ну и может быть ссылку на parent (для организации иерархии и контейнеров).

Comment: @avp: угу, вы правы, я только скелет набросал.